# Flutter onGenerateRoute builds multiple times

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter navigation as follows:

```
return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Title',
          onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
        );

    Route _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/') {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            print('route / build'); //<---------------check
            return LoginPage();
          });
    } else if (settings.name == '/someother') {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            return SomeOtherPage();
          });
    }
    return null;
  }
```

When app starts the LoginPage opens as expected and the check comment `'route / build'` prints to console. The LoginPage has two TextFields (username,password), when I focus on username field, the `'route / build'` prints again which means the LoginPage is rebuilt, when I fill username and go to next field (password) the page is rebuilt again and username value is lost.

Why the page is being rebuilt and how to solve it?

**UPDATE:** The real problem was not because of rebuilds but because of `FocusNode` in `LoginPage` which was `StatelessWidget` so `FocusNode` lifecycle was not managed. That caused text to dissapear and two focuses appear simultaneously on both `TextFields` on page rebuild.

Comment: Would you mind posting your login page code (Simplified/UI free)

Comment: @Abbas.M Sorry, you were right, the problem was in LoginPage, I should have posted it.